# Drive axis with slipping gear

Tags: motor, gearing

I'm looking for a name of the mechanic part (axis-gear combination) with the following description to use it in an automatic window control. I can't find this online to get parts due to the lack of right keywords. I'm sorry if I did use some wrong words to describe the part – I'm not from this field of technology:

**I have a remote motor and an effector gear that is at minimum placed 30 cm away from it alongside the motor axis. The axis has teeth on which the effector is grabbing on. The gear is not strongly mounted on the axis, though: When the motor turns, it turns as well but it can still freely slip up and down the axis.**

[image]

What is this called?

Comment: Please honor my painting skills.

Comment: google `parts in manual transmission` and look at the pictures ... you may find a technical name for the gear ... a quick search indicates that it may not have a specific name

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of @jsotola (pls. give him an upvote) with the manual transmission parts I found out that this is called the **reverse sliding gear** and the **reverse sliding gear shaft** when used in manual transmissions for, well, the reverse gear in cars.

More technically it is simply known as **slide gear**:

[image: Slide gear]

([Image source](https://pdxrvwholesale.com/products/18-tooth-slide-out-spur-gear-122739))